# how to generate sequence of ones and zeros in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to generate a sequence of ones and zeros in using bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
clock=1
n=1
# continue until $n equals 5
while [ $n -le 5 ]
do
    echo "$clock"
    n=$(( n+1 ))     # increments $n
    clock=$(~clock)
done
```

Expected output:
1
0
1
0
1

Output generated from the above code:
I am getting error from this line: clock=$(~clock)
Error: ~clock: command not found

Comment: What is `~clock` supposed to mean ? Also you can remove the quotes from `$clock`

Comment: @Saksow `~` is the bitwise NOT operator used in arithmetic expressions (which is what the OP presumably wants to use, `$((...))` instead of `$(...)`). The quotes aren't hurting anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate sequence with 1 and 0 alternatively, you can use

```
#!/bin/bash
clock=1
n=1
# continue until $n equals 5
while [ $n -le 5 ]
do
    echo "$clock"
    n=$(( n+1 ))     
    # increments $n
    clock=$((clock+1))
    clock=$((clock%2))
done
```

If you want to generate random sequence of 1 and 0s, you can use

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
# continue until $n equals 5
while [ $n -le 5 ]
do
    echo "$((RANDOM%2))"
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in this line:

```
clock=$(~clock)
```

Here bash is trying to run anything inside `$(...)` as a command (it is called command substitution).

Using `~clock` is also incorrect as it will only do **bitwise negation** and will not produce `1` and `0` as you are expecting.

You can use this script to get alternate `1` and `0` printed:

```
#!/bin/bash
clock=1
# continue until $n equals 5
for ((n=0; n<5; n++))
do
    echo "$clock"
    clock=$((1 - clock))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short way to do it

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
  echo $((i%2))
done
```

Or slightly less concise but easier to configure with variables to define the loop :

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
  echo $((i%2))
done
```

Another one, just for fun (would not do that in a read script, more like a little puzzle to figure out why it works).  Remove the "false" line to begin with 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
false
for i in {1..5}
do
  echo $? ; [[ $_ != 0 ]]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the following trick using the brace expansion.

```
echo {,,,,}{1,0}
```

This one will generate 5 pairs of ones and zeroes.